# redis pipeline and pipeline

Tags: redis, pipeline

The essence of the redis pipeline is to change the read and write order of the instructions in the pipeline. We usually say that the pipeline is a means of inter-process communication, and the redis pipeline is socket-based communication, the two are not comparable, is there a problem with this understanding?

Answer (score 1):

An interprocess pipes and Redis' network pipelining are different things. One is explained at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/inter_process_communication/inter_process_communication_pipes.htm and the other at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_pipelining

Answer (score 0):

Both are different:

**Redis pipeline** is a network optimization strategy implemented on clients, where multiple commands are sent to Redis-Server at once.
More about redis-pipeline on: https://buildatscale.tech/what-is-redis-pipeline/

**Unix pipelines** are mechanisms for inter-process communication. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)